# What's wrong with preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to resolve a preg_replace mistery with no success, perhaps you can help me. I have this sentence:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\[_BEGIN_\](.*?)\[_END_\]/", '', $string);
```

It removes all content between any `[_BEGIN_]` and `[_END_]` meta-tags. For example applied to:

```
"The [_BEGIN_] quick brown [_END_]fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

gives as result:

```
"The fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

The problem is it works in my development machine (Ubuntu 9.10, PHP v5.2.10) but in my production site (Gentoo 1.6.14, PHP v5.2.5-pl1-gentoo) it fails (preg_replace returns the same input string).

There is any problem with the regex used? How can I fix this problem? How to debug it? Any clue will be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Your regex seems fine. I don't know PHP, but I've heard that there are differences between single and double quotes. Does using single quotes around the regex change anything?

Comment: @TimPietzcker it works perfectly on "normal" systems: http://codepad.org/1u5HEX9R

Comment: @Ivan try to make a simple `preg_replace` test file and see if that works. Have you enabled errors and warnings?

Comment: Yes, no errors or warnings. I've made a simple test (a piece of code like the @TimPietzcker codepad and it is not reproduced. I only reproduce it in the middle of hundreds and hundreds of lines of code :-O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `\C` anywhere in the list of escape sequences. Shouldn't it be `(.*?)` instead of `(\C*?)`?

Comment: I agree, I've never heard of `\C`. I'd go for `/\[_BEGIN_\](.*?)\[_END_\]/`. Maybe the `\C` is something platform specific?

Comment: I've doble checked that and no success. I've edited the question to point that this is not the problem. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`\C` is the same as:

```
[^-._:A-Za-z0-9]
```

Try to change it to this since not all flavors have support for `\C`

Comment: Interesting! Do you have a reference containing it? Cannot find it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php :(

Comment: That's not the problem. I've double checked that and found the same behaivour. I've edited the question to remark that's not the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Marcus Ah, so it's not PHP-specific in some versions, but general part of some regex implementations like in .NET. Thanks!